# python pandas - groupby unstack pivot - count len - mixed values and export

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to combine data from a file of approximately 70,000 lines. For several types of results, I need to export file (csv type for example)

The file that contains the data after import returns this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'sec_Id':["to","ti","tu","ta","ty","te"], 
 'sec_Orga':['CNP','COF','COF','POS','POS','POS'], 
 'sec_Etat':['Sorti(e)','Valide','Suspendu(e)','Valide','Suspendu(e)','Suspendu(e)']
 })


df
Out[59]: 
      sec_Etat  sec_Id  sec_Orga
0     Sorti(e)      to       CNP
1       Valide      ti       COF
2  Suspendu(e)      tu       COF
3       Valide      ta       POS
4  Suspendu(e)      ty       POS
5  Suspendu(e)      te       POS
```

and in the end I have this souhaterais total result:

```
      Total  Valide  Suspendu(e)  Sorti(e)
CNP       1       0            0         1
COF       2       1            1         0
POS       3       1            2         0
```

as you see it's a values combining 'total' column with unique values of 'sec_Etat" column in title...

i'd tryed with groupby, unstake, pivot but nothing worked...

After that I must export the data for a csv file... how could I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pivot_table` method. For the `aggfunc` argument, use `len`. This will return the count of the items for the provided `index` and `column`. Finally, just sum the rows along `axis=1`. Use `.to_csv` to export.

See code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sec_Id': ["to", "ti", "tu", "ta", "ty", "te"],
    'sec_Orga': ['CNP', 'COF', 'COF', 'POS', 'POS', 'POS'],
    'sec_Etat': ['Sorti(e)', 'Valide', 'Suspendu(e)', 'Valide', 'Suspendu(e)', 'Suspendu(e)']
})

pivot = df.pivot_table(index='sec_Orga', columns='sec_Etat', aggfunc=len)
pivot["total"] = pivot.sum(axis=1)

print pivot

# pivot.to_csv("p.csv") # Export to CSV file. Uncomment to use.
```

Comment: Realy thank you for your answer!! it match perfectly!!

Comment: but i have 2 question about solution: 
here the result: